# Running a PyTorch dataloader/Dataset on multiple distributed CPUs

Tags: python, mpi, pytorch, distributed-computing

I wonder if there is a way to distributed the dataloader/Dataset to many CPUs, even when using a single GPU.
Specifically, I would like to have a Dataset class, and the `__getitem__` function will be distributed across many different CPUs (using mpi maybe? but any other way is also good).

Thanks

**EDIT**
My title was erroneously edited, I am not trying to distribute the model itslef, I only want to distribute the data loading/parsing of the model

**EDIT - 2**
Some interesting discussion in this direction is available [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49440)

Comment: The default behavior of a `DataLoader` when initialized with `num_workers` greater than zero is to spawn worker processes and load data in parallel when iterated over

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is constrained by the amount of cpu cores available on the computer. I have a cluster of 100s of CPUs, and I would like to ask all of those CPUs to prepare data for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fetching data from remote server in pytorch dataloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339453/fetching-data-from-remote-server-in-pytorch-dataloader) is kinda a duplicate of your question so I can suggest the same answer.

I've written [RPCDataloader](https://github.com/CEA-LIST/RPCDataloader) to distribute dataloader workers on remote servers. It's not using mpi (yet) because the bandwidth on simple TCP sockets (over IB) was sufficient in my case, and I can get the node configuration from SLURM.

It takes 3 steps to use:

1. Start workers on the data node: `python -m rpcdataloader.launch --host=0.0.0.0 --port=xxxx`
2. Create dataset in the trainer(s), this will instantiate actual datasets on the workers and a placeholder object in the trainer(s):

```
dataset = rpcdataloader.RPCDataset(
    workers=['node01:6543', 'node02:5432'],
    dataset=torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder,
    root=args.data_path + "/train",
    transform=train_transform)
```

3. Create Dataloader:

```
dataloader = rpcdataloader.RPCDataloader(
    dataset
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=True,
    pin_memory=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this of course, but mind you - it is not always very effective for general Machine Learning needs, due to the hefty communication costs.
Use `DistributedDataParallel`

> Implements distributed data parallelism that is based on
>   torch.distributed package at the module level.
>
> This container parallelizes the application of the given module by
>   splitting the input across the specified devices by chunking in the
>   batch dimension. The module is replicated on each machine and each
>   device, and each such replica handles a portion of the input. During
>   the backwards pass, gradients from each node are averaged.

In practice, I'd recommend you utilize the `pytorch_lightning` package, to reduce some of the boilerplate code you need to write for this to work.

Reference: 
[DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#distributeddataparallel),[pytorch_lightning](https://github.com/williamFalcon/pytorch-lightning)

Comment: Thanks @Mano, my title was edited erroneously. I am not trying to distribute the model itself. I want to distribute the data-loading/ data-parsing. Thanks