# Fetching data from remote server in pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a large hd5 file (~100GB) containing image features from resnet. This file is located on my local machine (laptop). My model is trained on cluster node that has storage limit of 25GB.
Right now, I am using torch.distributed.rpc for tranferring data from my local machine to cluster.
I am exposing a server on my local machine in the following way,

> num_worker = 4
>
> utils.WORLD_SIZE = num_worker + 1

```
import os
import torch
import utils
import torch.distributed.rpc as rpc

def run_worker(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '8888'
    
    rpc.init_rpc(utils.SERVER_NAME,
                 rank = rank, 
                 world_size = world_size)
    print("Server Initialized", flush=True)
    rpc.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rank = 0
    world_size = utils.WORLD_SIZE
    run_worker(rank, world_size)
```

This server sends data from local machine to cluster. (other classes are omitted)

Now for requesting data from cluster, I am initializing rpc for each worker using **worker_init_fn** for dataloader,

```
def worker_init_fn(worker_id):
    rpc.init_rpc(utils.CLIENT_NAME.format(worker_id+1),
                rank=worker_id+1, world_size=utils.WORLD_SIZE)
    
    worker_info = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()
    dataset = worker_info.dataset
    worker_id = worker_info.id
    server_info = rpc.get_worker_info(utils.SERVER_NAME)
    dataset.server_ref = rpc.remote(server_info, utils.Server)
```

Now, when I run my code, the training loop completes one iteration of the dataset and hangs after that and I get the following error on cluster side,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom_datasets.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "custom_datasets.py", line 110, in main
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(mn_dataset_loader):
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 856, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 881, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 394, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 135, in _worker_loop
    init_fn(worker_id)
  File "custom_datasets.py", line 78, in worker_init_fn
    rank=worker_id+1, world_size=utils.WORLD_SIZE)
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/rpc/__init__.py", line 67, in init_rpc
    store, _, _ = next(rendezvous_iterator)
  File "/home/kanishk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 168, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = TCPStore(master_addr, master_port, world_size, start_daemon)
RuntimeError: connect() timed out.
```

Above problem doesn't occur when I set num_worker = 0, but the cluster code is very slow. I think the error is because of multi-threading but I am not sure how to resolve this. Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: How long does the first training set take to complete? You might be idle timing out the socket if it takes too long. You should be able to configure a longer timeout period somewhere.

Comment: First iteration takes ~350 sec, but this is on dummy data of mnist images, on my actual data it takes ~30 min. I tried adding a timeout using rpc_backend_options, but the issue still persists. It hangs after first epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm a bit late to the party but I can suggest my own library [RPCDataloader](https://github.com/CEA-LIST/RPCDataloader).

It doesn't use `pytorch.rpc` which I have found a bit cumbersome for that purpose (and slow). Internally it uses a basic TCP-based rpc.
It takes 3 steps to use:

1. Start workers on the data node: `python -m rpcdataloader.launch --host=0.0.0.0 --port=xxxx`
2. Create dataset in the trainer(s), this will instantiate actual datasets on data nodes and handles in the trainer(s):

```py
dataset = rpcdataloader.RPCDataset(
    workers=['node01:6543', 'node02:5432'],
    dataset=torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder,
    root=args.data_path + "/train",
    transform=train_transform)
```

3. Create Dataloader:

```py
dataloader = rpcdataloader.RPCDataloader(
    dataset
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=True,
    pin_memory=True)
```